# How to create individual list for different objects in Java?

Tags: java, oop

What I'm trying to achieve - have a list that is **not** shared by all the objects i.e. have a unique list for each objects created from a class, something similar to the below code which obviously results in an error because the ArrayList needs to be static.

```
public class Foo{
   public ArrayList<String> chain = new ArrayList<>();
   public addElement(String input){
        this.chain.add(input);
   }
}
public printList(){
  for(String s : this.chain){
     System.out.println(s);
  }
}
public static void main(){
  Foo x = new Foo();
  Foo y = new Foo();

  x.addElement("abc");
  x.addElement("pqr"); 

  y.addElement("lmn");
  y.addElement("rty");

  x.printList(); //print abc pqr
  y.printList(); //print lmn rty
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the above outputs?

Comment: There is a serious issue in `public addElement(String input)` because it does not define a return type in its signature. Write `public void addElement(String input)` instead...

Comment: I would like to know why you think that "obviously ... ArrayList needs to be static". It seems like this whole question is based on a misconception.

Comment: @KYL3R nope, this us just java 8 diamond operator, you don't need to specify twice, imagine `Map<String, List<Map<String,Integer>>> m = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer> becomes = new HashMap<>`

Comment: thanks, didn't know that :)

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets are all over the place, you miss function return types and their names and calls don't match, moreso your main doesn't follow the normal pattern. In other words it could use some help.

```
public class Foo
{
public ArrayList<String> chain = new ArrayList<>();


public void addElement( String input )
{
    this.chain.add( input );
}


public void printList()
{
    for( String s : this.chain )
    {
        System.out.println( s );
    }
}


public static void main(String args[])
{
    Foo x = new Foo();
    Foo y = new Foo();

    x.addElement( "abc" );
    x.addElement( "pqr" );

    y.addElement( "lmn" );
    y.addElement( "rty" );

    x.printList(); //print abc pqr
    y.printList(); //print lmn rty
}
}
```

This should work, from my understanding of what you want. You might wanna initialize ArrayList in constructor - but thats your choice.

Comment: This programme will ask to change `chain` variable to static. It won't even compile

Comment: @DebmalyaBiswas why would it? I compiled it successfully without any problems.